# What is an STG Region in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, region

Found in locations/regions appended by `STG` when running `az vm list-skus --size "Standard_A" --resource-type "virtualMachines" --output table`. Example `SouthCentralUSSTG`.

Not sure what does it mean. Is this a valid region to be used in azure location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to list the all-region in azure  i didn't found any region like STG AFAIK, it's not valid to use in azure

Comment: Okay, thank you. Maybe it is labelled as `locations`. I can see most of the regions appended with `STG` when I run the command above.  Others have `EUAP`. Notice in this photo: https://i.ibb.co/wY44b2j/Screenshot-2022-07-15-014443.png

Comment: please check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.locationnames.centraluseuap?view=azure-dotnet) EUAP stands for ***Early Updates Access Program*** its special canary regions in Azure

Comment: yep, am aware of that. Was looking for what does STG stands for.

Comment: STG is Synonymous with Azure Storage. Software stack is frequently referred to as STG.